# can't unenroll users created by external database form course in moodle

Tags: database, external, moodle

I am having a problem in moodle 2.8. Some users where added by external database and some where added manual.

The problem is that the users enrolled by external database cant be unenrolled from the course, the button for unenroll appear in the users created manually but in the others don't.

If there is a fast way to unenroll them and a way to prevent this to happen it would be helpful.

Comment: What system created the users?  Was it from an Authentication plugin in Moodle, or using the Moodle API?  Are they being auto-enrolled onto courses in that step, or by a different plugin?  Which enrolment methods are available for the course(s) in question?

Comment: Is this any use to you? It didn't work for me sadly because I got an error message saying it is not an external function. Meh.
https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-28592